# There are processes named 'apache2' running

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

help me resolve this error in apache

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

error:

There are processes named 'apache2' running which do not match your pid file which are left untouched in the name of safety, Please review the situation by hand.

thanks

Answer (score 30):

Kill them.

`kill -9 $(ps -e | grep apache2 | awk '{print $1}')`

Answer (score 8):

Before killing the process, maybe, you would like to check if the pid file path set in

> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

equals the one stated in APACHE_PID_FILE environment variable exported in the :

> /etc/apache2/envvars

file.

Saving a process snapshot before proceeding to kill, would be helpful :

```
# top -b -n1 > /tmp/process.log
```

Then get the pid of apache2 with :

```
pidof apache2
```

It output the related processes id(s) e.g 4920 4919. Then kill them with :

```
sudo kill -9 pid
```

replacing pid with the process id(s) you got from the previous output.

Finally restart Apache 2 server :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Next time would be helpful letting others know basic things about your OS distro etc.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This is actually useful information. `service apache2 restart` and `apache2ctl restart` behaves differently based on where they read information from.

Answer (score 0):

none of these answers worked.. this did

```
kill -9 $(pidof apache2)
```

Comment: Are you sure? You tried my answer forthe same problem as the OP and didn't worked?I am SURE you didn't  or else you don't  actually know what you are doing..

Comment: lol and I am SURE did.. but thanks for following up. I would not have gone to the effort of adding this if a previous answer had fixed the issue.. it did not.  So I have added what did.. I believe this is how it is supposed to work here.

Comment: Answer has been tested on 2 different apache servers .It just works.So simple

Comment: Typically your method could return dozens of process ids. This method kills than all off in 1 simple command