# There are processess named 'apache2' running - permanent fix

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, cakephp, apache2

Some time ago I started getting this error:

**There are processes named 'apache2' running which do not match your pid file which are left untouched in the name of safety, Please review the situation by hand.**

That happens every time I restart the system, my hosts are down and I get this error while restarting.

The simple solution for that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491533/there-are-processes-named-apache2-running). Although I don't want to do that every time I start the PC.

EDIT: We got a new worker and had him install a new installation on Ubuntu, he then joined the same project I'm working on and all of a sudden he started getting the same error as above. This has to have something to do with the project we're working on, which is built in CakePHP 2.1.3.

One particular difference with that project was that we had to create local SSL certificates. We based that off this site:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/linux-apache-mod-ssl-generate-key-csr-crt-file/

There's some settings using mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file too which I don't really understand to be honest. I only took over this project recently. Here's the file content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^cron-5min.php cron-5min.php [L]
RewriteRule backup.php backup.php [L]

RewriteRule cron_log_U82178hhbbhn.txt cron_log.txt [L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*) uploads/$1 [L]
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```